# Kafka Consumer error: Marking coordinator dead

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 10 partitions in Kafka 0.10.0.1 cluster. I have an application that spawns multiple consumer threads. For this topic I am spawning 5 threads. Many times in my application logs I am seeing this entry

```
INFO :: AbstractCoordinator:600 - Marking the coordinator x.x.x.x:9092
(id:2147483646 rack: null) dead for group notifications-consumer
```

Then there are several entries saying `(Re-)joining group notifications-consumer.`
Afterwards I also see one warning saying

```
Auto commit failed for group notifications-consumer: Commit cannot be completed since
the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means
that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured
max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time 
message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout
or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned by poll() with max.poll.records.
```

Now I have already adjusted my consumer config like so

```
props.put("max.poll.records", 200);
props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", 20000);
props.put("session.timeout.ms", 60000);
```

So, even after properly adjusting the config I am still getting this error. During the rebalance our app is completely unresponsive. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `session.timeout.ms` you only control the timeouts due to heartbeats, this means that has passed `session.timeout.ms` milliseconds since the last heartbeat and the cluster declares you as a dead node and triggers a rebalance.

Before [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) the heartbeat was sent within the poll but now is moved to a specific background thread to avoid being evicted from the cluster if you were taking more time than `session.timeout.ms` to call another `poll()`. 
Separating the heartbeat to a specific thread decouples the processing from telling the cluster that you are up and running, but this introduced the risk of "livelock" situations in which the process is alive, but is not making progress, so besides making the heartbeat independent of the `poll` a new timeout was introduced to ensure that the consumer was alive and making progress.
The documentation says these about the implementation pre KIP-62:

> As long as the consumer is sending heartbeats, it basically holds a lock on the partitions it was assigned. If the process becomes defunct in such a way that it cannot make progress but is nevertheless continuing to send heartbeats, then no other member in the group will be able to take over the partitions, which causes increasing lag. The fact that heartbeating and processing is all done in the same thread, however, guarantees that consumers must make progress to keep their assignment. Any stall which affects processing also affects heartbeats.

The changes introduced by the KIP-62 includes:

> Decoupling the processing timeout: We propose to introduce a separate locally enforced timeout for record processing and a background thread to keep the session active until this timeout expires. We call this new timeout as the "process timeout" and expose it in the consumer's configuration as max.poll.interval.ms. This config sets the maximum delay between client calls to poll()

From the logs you posted I think you may be in this situation, your app is taking more time than `max.poll.interval.ms` (5 min by default) to process the 200 polled records.
If you are in this scenario you could only reduce even more the `max.poll.records` or increase the `max.poll.interval.ms`.

### PD:

The `max.poll.interval.ms` configuration that appears on your log is from (at least) kafka 0.10.1.0 so I assume you make a little mistake there.

### Update

Correct me if I understood you wrong but in your last comment you were saying that you are creating 25 consumers (e.g. 25 `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` if you were using java) and suscribing them to N different topics but using the same `group.id`.
If this is correct, you will see rebalacing each time a `KafkaConsumer` is started or stopped because it will send a `JoinGroup` or `LeaveGroup` message (see the corresponding [kafka protocol](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/protocol.html)) that contains `group.id` and `member.id` (the `member.id` is not the host so two consumers created in the same process will still have different ids). Note that these message doesn't contain topic subscription information (although that information should be in the brokers but kafka doesn't use it for rebalancing).
So each time the cluster receives a `JoinGroup` or a `LeaveGroup` for `group.id` X, it will trigger a rebalance for all consumers with the same `group.id`  X.

If you start 25 consumers with the same `group.id` you will see rebalancing until the last consumer is created and the corresponding rebalancing ends (if you continue seeing this you may be stopping consumers).

I had [this issue a couple months ago](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201804.mbox/browser).

> If we have two KafkaConsumer using the same group.id (running in the same process or in two different processes) and one of them is closed, it triggers a rebalance in the other KafkaConsumer even if they were subscribed to different topics.
>   I suppose that brokers must be taking into account only the group.id for a rebalance and not the subscribed topics corresponding to the pair (group_id,member_id) of the LeaveGroupRequest but I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior or it's something that should be improved?
>   I guess that is probably the first option to avoid a more complex rebalance in the broker and considering that the solution is very simple, i.e. just use different group ids for different KafkaConsumer that subscribe to different topics even if they are running in the same process.

---

> When rebalance occurs we see duplicate messages coming

This is the expeceted behaviour, one consumer consumes the message but before commiting the offset a rebalance was triggered and the commit fails. When the rebalance finished the process that will have that topic assignment will consume the message again (until commit success).

> I segregated into two groups, now suddenly problem has disappeared since past 2 hours.

You hit the nail on the head here, but if you don't want to see any (avoidable) rebalancing you should use a different `group.id` for each topic.

Here is a [great talk](https://youtu.be/QaeXDh12EhE?t=1364) about different rebalancing scenarios.

Comment: Didn't get your last statement `you make a little mistake there`. Where exactly?

Comment: Hi, got your point. I made changes in max.poll.interval.ms as well. I have set it to 600000 ms, i.e 10 minutes. Still consumer group rebalanced. and now I am continuously getting `WARN :: auto commit failed`

Comment: How are you doing partition assignment? Also, are you seeing at least one message being consumed?

Comment: partition assignment is automatic. Messages are getting consumed. But there are so many issues. When rebalance occurs we see duplicate messages coming. Now even after setting max.poll.records as low as 5 and setting max.poll.interval.ms as high as 10 minutes, still we saw commit failed. However, I did one thing. We were consuming from multiple topics and putting them under single consumer group. I segregated into two groups, now suddenly problem has disappeared since past 2 hours. Any idea why this could have happened? We had 25 consumers in that group. All on single server

Comment: Regarding Your comment, `you will see rebalancing until the last consumer is created`. Now I have different CG for every topic. But now I see that for some topics consumers don't start until after 5 minutes my process is restarted. Could it be happening because I am starting multiple consumers one after another? But then how else to start them?