# Which kafka property decides Poll frequency for KafkaConsumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand kafka in some details with respect to kafka streams (kafka stream client to kafka).

I understand that KafkConsumer (java client) would get data from kafka, however I am not able to understand at which frequency does client poll kakfa topic to fetch the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The frequency of the poll is defined by your code because you're responsible to call poll.
A very naive example of user code using KafkaConsumer is like the [following](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html)

```java
public class KafkaConsumerExample {
  ...


    static void runConsumer() throws InterruptedException {
        final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = createConsumer();

        final int giveUp = 100;   int noRecordsCount = 0;

        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(1000);

            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                noRecordsCount++;
                if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
                else continue;
            }

            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                        record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });

            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
        consumer.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

In this case the frequency is defined by the duration of processing the messages in `consumerRecords.forEach`.

However, keep in mind that if you don't call poll "fast enough" your consumer will be considered dead by the broker coordinator and a rebalance will be triggered.
This "fast enough" is determined by the property `max.poll.interval.ms` in kafka >= 0.10.1.0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50420562/3517383) for more details.

`max.poll.interval.ms` default value is five minutes, so if your `consumerRecords.forEach` takes longer than that your consumer will be considered dead.

If you don't want to use the raw `KafkaConsumer` directly you could use [alpakka kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/home.html), a library for consume from and produce to kafka topics in a **safe** and backpressured way (is based on akka streams).
With this library, the frequency of poll is determined by configuration `akka.kafka.consumer.poll-interval`.
We say is safe because it will continue polling to avoid the consumer is considered dead even when your processing can't keep up the rate. It's able to do this because `KafkaConsumer` allows pausing the consumer

```java
    /**
     * Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to {@link #poll(Duration)} will not return
     * any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using {@link #resume(Collection)}.
     * Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group
     * rebalance when automatic assignment is used.
     * @param partitions The partitions which should be paused
     * @throws IllegalStateException if any of the provided partitions are not currently assigned to this consumer
     */
    @Override
    public void pause(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) { ... }
```

To fully understand this you should read about akka-streams and backpressure.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was under the impression that this happens automatically and we don't do anything for polling()

Comment: Please mark as correct if this answered your question

Comment: One more question,  when we write stream-processor we don't write poll(), that come as part of API itself, but in there does it have similar mechanism?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly with stream-processor, but every consumer that its build upon `KafkaConsumer` uses this mechanism. And even if they don't use the `KafkaConsumer` they **must** use the kafka protocol, in particular the message [Fetch](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Fetch) for getting records.

Comment: I am taking about kafka stream processors, in which we build Topology, having source processor and sink processor. The source processor fetched data from Kafka.

Comment: You mean kafka streams, ok.
From [javadoc](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/6243db2c095a7aebb72b359ea05c18e5987ae780/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java#L104)  

`Internally a {@code KafkaStreams} instance contains a normal {@link KafkaProducer} and {@link KafkaConsumer} instance
 * that is used for reading input and writing output.`

Comment: Yes  I am talking about kafka streams. So do we have any parameter which controls the polling interval?

Comment: In Kafka Streams, I think you should check the `StreamsConfig.POLL_MS_CONFIG` configuration.  You can look for "poll.ms" in https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#optional-configuration-parameters and in the JavaDoc : https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.html#POLL_MS_CONFIG

Comment: This answer missed the core of the question that is about Kafka Streams. A similar question was answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379412/how-many-times-kafka-stream-invokes-poll-for-fetching-records-from-kafka-topic

Comment: Seems both questions are from @CuriousMind -- please don't post duplicate question. I would recommend to delete this question, because the other question has an appropriate answer already.

Comment: what about in Kafka Streaming applications ? This Thread.sleep is hardcoded in the KStreamAPIs?